# Ahrefs.com Site Audit quite often incorrectly reports broken links to NextJS JavaScript files

Tags: cloudflare, ahrefs

Our site uses NextJS. When the site is rebuilt after code changes, the links to JavaScript files change.

Quite often, the `Ahrefs.com` site audit crawl detects links to broken JS files.

Every time I have manually checked the pages that `Ahrefs.com` reported as having broken JS files (on the same day the `Ahrefs.com` scan was completed), there are no 404s in the console.

The site uses Cloudflare caching.

Could Cloudflare caching be causing the problem for `Ahrefs.com`?

If so, why is it not causing a problem for me?

Comment: I think it is loading time.  I get a few from ahrefs as well (and I dont have any js on those pages)

Comment: To confirm whether this is the case, you could try clearing the Cloudflare cache and then re-running the Ahrefs.com audit to see if it still detects broken JS files. If the issue persists, it may be worth contacting Ahrefs.com support.